# onchange of textbox will add corresponding textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.floor').change(function() {
    var floor1 = parseInt($('#firstfloor').val(), 10);
    var floor2 = parseInt($('#secondfloor').val(), 10);
    var floor3 = parseInt($('#thirdfloor').val(), 10);
    var floor4 = parseInt($('#fourthfloor').val(), 10);

    var storey = $('#nostorey').val();
    alert(storey);
    if(storey === 1){
        var total = floor1;
    }else if(storey === 2){
        var total = floor1 + floor2;
    }else if(storey === 3){
        var total = floor1 + floor2 + floor3;
    }else{
        var total = floor1 + floor2 + floor3 + floor4;
    }



    console.log(total);
    $('#area_total').val(total);
    });
```

I have here 5 input `on for determining the number of floors` and `1 for each floor` i want to get the total area of the building by adding the area of each floor depending on the number of floors. What i did is to get the value or number of storey of the building then depeding on the value i have `if` statement to add what floor to add. Except for giving all 4 input value the rest will give `NaN` as result. Any idea is appreciated.

`UPDATE`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/av52163y/)

Comment: Can you post `jsfiddle` code so we can help as more expected for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all ifs and just sum all areas:

```
$('.floor').change(function() {
  var floor1 = parseInt($('#firstfloor').val(), 10) || 0;
  var floor2 = parseInt($('#secondfloor').val(), 10) || 0;
  var floor3 = parseInt($('#thirdfloor').val(), 10) || 0;
  var floor4 = parseInt($('#fourthfloor').val(), 10) || 0;
  var total = floor1 + floor2 + floor3 + floor4;

  console.log(total);
  $('#area_total').val(total);
});
```

Comment: max can i add something on this kind of solution just to make it a bit fancy or i need to put back the `if`, i am thinking if `floorX === 0` then the input with be readonly can i add it in your sample?

Comment: i can do it like `if(floor1 == 0){$('#firstfloor').attr('readonly', true);}else if...` i just wan t to know if it is also feasible without `ifs`.

Comment: I don't understand such behavior. If you set input to readonly, how can you set this state back? It is another task in the area of user experience

Comment: setting it again in a way that `if(floor != 0){$('#firstfloor').attr('readonly', false);}else if...`

Comment: I can't help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Better add some class to your inputs, like **.floor-input** then do like

```
// values of your floors will store in this array
var values = [];

// get floor values
$('.floor-input').each(function() {
    values.push(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0);
});

// get sum of all floors
var total = values.reduce(function(sum, val) {
    return sum + val;
}, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Now you able to add any number of floors without code changes